# pm2 restart loop in AWS Elastic Beansalk (Node environment)

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pm2

I have a NodeJs environment built in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  I'm using pm2 to monitor 2 different NodeJS apps uploaded to environment.  The kicker is I need to make sure the `local` app is started before the `gateway` app starts.  I'm using `npm-run-all` synchronously to start apps in a specific order.

Here's my package.json:

```
"start": "npm-run-all -s start:local start:gateway",
"start:local": "pm2 start ./ecosystem.config.js --only local-service --env production",
"start:gateway": "pm2 start ./ecosystem.config.js --only gateway-service --env production",
```

Here's my ecosystem.config file:

```
module.exports =
{
  apps:
    [
      {
        name: 'local-service',
        script: './dist/services/local.js',
        watch: false,
        interpreter: 'node',
        interpreter_args: '--require ts-node/register --require tsconfig-paths/register',
        autorestart: false
      },
      {
        name: 'gateway-service',
        script: './dist/server.js',
        watch: false,
        interpreter: 'node',
        interpreter_args: '--require ts-node/register --require tsconfig-paths/register',
        wait_ready: true,
        listen_timeout: 5000,
        autorestart: false
      }
    ]
};
```

The elastic beanstalk log is indicating `start` in package.json is continuously being called.  I've configured each app to not restart, but there seems to be something else causing the continuous restart to happen.  I'm getting `502 Bad Gateway` error when trying to access the gateway-service itself.

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use just pm2 ecosystem without `npm-run-all`, i.e. just `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` and allow any (re)start sequences, because in real life your `gateway` & `local` apps can be restarted in different orders.

So instead of using start scheduling logic - please consider to move that logic to your `local` app - to monitor & re-connect on connection failure with `gateway` app.

In case you still want to use start scheduling logic, please take a look at [pm2 process actions](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-actions/) and add to `gateway` app code to trigger starting your `local` app.